# DAX Year over Year

Tags: dax, powerbi

I have been trying to get this DAX expression to show me cumulative searches for last financial year.  Here is an example of the information;

```
Fiscal Week    Fiscal Year    Searches    Brand
1              14             1000        Example1
1              15             1200        Example1
2              14             1000        Example1
2              15             1200        Example2
```

My formula below is working a little, but when I apply an slicers to the data it breaks in PowerBI.  i.e. if I slice by another field, like brand.

```
Cum. Searches PY = 
IF (
HASONEVALUE ( 'data'[Fiscal Year] ),
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'data'[Searches] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL( 'data' ),
        'data'[Fiscal Year.] = VALUES ( 'data'[Fiscal Year] ) - 1
            && CONTAINS(
                VALUES ( 'data'[Fiscal Week] ),
                'data'[Fiscal Week],
                'data'[Fiscal Week] )
    )
),
BLANK ()
)
```

I'd appreciate any pointers to where I'm going wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be simplified, I dont understand the need for the HASONEVALUE or CONTAINS functions. I would use something like the following for your measure:

`Cum. Searches PY:= CALCULATE( 
    SUM( Table1[Searches] ), 
    FILTER( 
        ALL( Table1[Fiscal Year] ) , 
        Table1[Fiscal Year] = MAX( Table1[Fiscal Year] ) - 1
    ) 
)`

With that sample data above, this will produce results of:

`Example1   2000
Example2   (Blank)`

If that's not your expected result, then explain exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this works perfectly. Sorry, I am new to DAX and still learning!  Now I need to figure out how to only show the 'This Year' equivalent!  My solution so far shows both years!