# Year over Year difference in Power BI matrix with year filter

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, measure

I have the following dataset:

| year | category | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | shoes | 47,84 |
| 2001 | pants | 106,85 |
| 2002 | shoes | 30,57 |
| 2002 | pants | 103,08 |
| 2003 | shoes | 32,64 |
| 2003 | pants | 85,08 |

Based on this dataset I create the following matrix in Power BI:
[image]

I need to calculate the year-over-year difference for two consecutive years including a year filter, so that I get this:

[image]

To achieve my desired result, I created the following measure:

```
Diff =
IF (
    ISFILTERED ( Sheet1[year] ),
    SUM ( Sheet1[sales] ),
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Sheet1[sales] ), Sheet1[year] = "2003" )
        - CALCULATE ( SUM ( Sheet1[sales] ), Sheet1[year] = "2002" )
)
```

but instead I got this:

[image]

Can you help? thanks

Comment: You may want to Google for YoY calculation  with DAX. The standard approach is to use a linked date table and the DAX built-in time intelligence. Regarding your measure, you may want to keep in mind that the visual you are using also acts as a filter additionally to any filtering defined in your measure, i.e. the category and year in the matrix are also applied as filters. You may want to look for some functions related to filtering to e.g. “reset” the filter as needed, such as ALL () Good luck!

Comment: Some more inspiration beside the detailed approach from mkRabbani: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871093/dax-year-over-year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871093/dax-year-over-year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding another answer as I think my first answer can help others. Just follow these below steps.

**Step-1:** Create these below 7 measure-

```
text_category = "Category"
```

---

```
text_prev_year = MAX('your_table_name'[year]) - 1
```

---

```
text_this_year = MAX('your_table_name'[year])
```

---

```
text_diff = "YoY Diff"
```

---

```
max_year_sales = 

var max_year = MAX('your_table_name'[year])

return
CALCULATE(
    sum('your_table_name'[sales]),
    FILTER(    
        ALLEXCEPT('your_table_name','your_table_name'[category]),
        'your_table_name'[year] = max_year
    )
)
```

---

```
prev_year_sales = 

var prev_year = MAX('your_table_name'[year]) - 1

return
CALCULATE(
    sum('your_table_name'[sales]),
    FILTER(    
        ALLEXCEPT('your_table_name','your_table_name'[category]),
        'your_table_name'[year] = prev_year
    )
)
```

---

```
diff = [max_year_sales] - [prev_year_sales]
```

---

**Step-2:** Create the year slicer.

**Step-3:** Add a table visual and disable Header from the property. Then add these 4 measure to it- "text_category", "text_prev_year", "text_this_year" and "text_diff".

**Step-4:** Add another table and do the same - disable Header. Then add one column "category" and 3 measures- "prev_year_sales", "max_year_sales" and "diff" to the table.

The output will be something like the below-

[image]

Now just adjust both tables together and column widths in a way so that values in your first table seem like the header of your second table. You can group both tables as well after placing them in the appropriate place. The final output will be something like-

[image]

**Note:** This is not a standard solution.

Comment: You are most welcome and hope it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to achieve your required output-

**Step-1:** Create a new calculated table using the below code-

```
YearKey = DISTINCT(your_table_name[year])
```

**Step-2:** Now create the **year slicer** using the column created in the above-calculated table.

**Step-3:** Now create a new **Measure** with the below code-

```
check_this_and_prev_year = 
if(
    SELECTEDVALUE(YearKey[year]),
    IF(MAX(your_table_name[year])>(MAX(YearKey[Year])-2) && MAX(your_table_name[year])<=MAX(YearKey[Year]),1),
    1
)
```

**Step-4:** Create another **Measure** with the below code-

```
sum_of_sales = sum(your_table_name[sales]) * [check_this_and_prev_year]
```

**Step-5:** And create this final **Measure**-

```
yoy_diff = 

var curr_row_year = min(your_table_name[year])
var previous_year = curr_row_year - 1
var curr_category = min(your_table_name[category])

return
if(
    [check_this_and_prev_year] = 1,
    sum(your_table_name[sales]) -  
    CALCULATE(
        sum(your_table_name[sales]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(your_table_name),
            your_table_name[year] = previous_year
                && your_table_name[category] = curr_category
        )
    )
)
```

**Finally** add a **Matrix** visual with this below setup

[image]

**And** here is the output based on different year selections-

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: the result you generated is not my desired output, to see my desired output see my question, thx

Comment: I have checked your desired output. Is that ok if you have label like "selected year" and "previous year" instead of 2003 and 2002 as a column header? iIf yes, you can create 3 Measure - "selected_year_sales", "previous_year_sales" and third one with "YoY Diff" = [selected_year_sales] - [previous_year_sales]

Comment: your answer is close to my desired output, but I want to have measure 'yoy_diff' only once at the end of each row. Your solution displays measure 'yoy_diff' after each column. Can you please update your solution so that it displays 'yoy_diff' only at the end of each row? thanks

Comment: There is always a workaround. The solution will be not standard, but at least it will serve the requirement. This is difficult to describe all the steps here and as a result, I have added a sample PBI file here for your reference. Please download and check - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-r3JvkZ9oPuXPi0o_LSjBrXse06Cyu1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can't open the file, please publish here the steps, thanks

Comment: What error you are getting while downloading?

Comment: can't download the file for security reasons. If it's not too much work for you, then I would really appreciate it if you could post here the steps, thanks again for your help so far

Comment: Can you try once again with this link- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-r3JvkZ9oPuXPi0o_LSjBrXse06Cyu1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: as I told you before I can't open the link for security reasons. If it is possible then please post your steps here, thanks

Comment: oh, first I thought the issue is in file downloading. I will try... :)

Comment: appreciate it if you can make it, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253825/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-harry).